# Is there any algorithm which can determine the biconnected components of an undirected graph without storing "reverse" edges?

Tags: graph-theory

I would like to determine the biconnected components of an undirected graph, but I know only such algorithms based on storing the graph edges duplicated. Do you know any algorithm which has no need for the "reverse" edges?

Comment: Do you regard the algorithm by Hopcroft and Tarjan to be one that duplicates edges?  (It does store a DFS tree of the graph.)

Comment: I have looked into the algorithm described in http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/biconnectivity-in-a-graph/ where I recognized the duplications of the edges.

Comment: Yes, that's Hopcroft and Tarjan's algorithm.

Comment: Could you say me any other algorithm not storing reverse edges?

Comment: You could do it the dumb way, by "masking" one vertex at a time and checking whether the resulting graph is disconnected.  That gives you a quadratic algorithm.